# python scrapy sending data from function to function

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

i have this

```
def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    sites = sel.xpath('myXpath')
    for site in sites:
        Date = site.css('p[class=date]::text').extract()
        yield Request(Link, callback = self.parseOneCar)

def parseOneCar(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    Do somethings
```

I want to send the `Date` to the second spider.

How please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def parse(self, response):
    ...
    yield Request(Link, 
                  meta={'date': Date},
                  callback = self.parseOneCar)

def parseOneCar(self, response):
    ...
    Date = response.meta['date']
```

for more info [see the docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta)